# Имя страны из CLGeocoder не совпадает со всеми странами из NSLocale

Tags: ios, swift, locale

Мне надо по координатам получить имя страны, затем по имени страны получить **iso country code** (например, Russia --> RU). Проблема заключается в том, что из геокодера мне приходит **Lebanon**, а в NSLocale эта страна именуется как **Libanon**. 

Делаю всё так:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng) ) {
    (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
    if let countryName = placemarks?.first?.country {
        for localeCode in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes {
            let identifier = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeCode)
            let _countryName = identifier.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: localeCode)
            print(_countryName?.lowercased())
            if countryName.lowercased() == _countryName?.lowercased() {
                countryCode = localeCode as String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как разрешить эту ситуацию? 

 
Большое спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: а у вас язык запроса геокодера и язык локали совпадают? Как я понял Lebanon это Ливан по-английски, а Libanon по-немецки

Comment: @schmidt9 В настройках айфона локаль установлена как английская. Немецкий нигде не фигурирует, даже как одна из раскладок клавиатуры. 
Но за мысль благодарю, теперь хотя бы есть идеи что гуглить. 
Но если у вас есть ещё идеи, буду признателен услышать их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в цикле каждый раз создавали новую локаль на основе полученного кода страны (`let identifier = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeCode)`), отсюда расхождение

Вот так выдает корректно

```
// Beirut
let lat = 33.835934
let lng = 35.504438

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng), preferredLocale: locale as Locale) { (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
    if let countryName = placemarks?.first?.country {
        for localeCode in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes {
            let _countryName = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: localeCode)

            if countryName.lowercased() == _countryName?.lowercased() {
                print(localeCode)
            }

        }
    }
}
```